# Android: GCM Error - string/gcm_defaultSendorid Error:Duplicate resources error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to connect/register my Android app with GCM, however I am receiving the following error during build

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Advanced_Android_Development\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Advanced_Android_Development\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

When I verified both the files,I noticed that the only commonality is gcm_defaultSenderId attribute present in both the files. Can any one help me understand what the issue could be?

I downloaded the google-services.json file after creating a console project in firebase https://console.firebase.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue, When I verified both the files

[string/gcm_defaultSenderId] C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Advanced_Android_Development\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml [string/gcm_defaultSenderId] C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Advanced_Android_Development\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

I noticed that the only commonality is gcm_defaultSenderId attribute present in both the files. The gcm_defaultSenderid was changed in strings.xml to correctly build the package